# string values of bidimensional array into int values

Tags: php

I have an bidimensional array like this (all the values are strings)

```
Array ( 
[0]=>Array([ENE] => 22 [FEB] => 24)
[1]=>Array( [MAR] => 16 [ABR] => 33 )
[2]=>Array([MAY] => 18 [JUN] => 19)
)
```

But I need to make that string values into integer.

I found the following answer that works just with simple arrays.

If you have array like:

```
$runners = ["1","2","3","4"];
```

And if you want to covert them into integers and keep within array, following should do the job:

```
$newArray = array_map( create_function('$value', 'return (int)$value;'),
            $runners);
```

Do you have any idea about how to do the same but with bidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop the array and convert every value to in with like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $elements = $array[$i];
    $values = array_map(function($arrayElement) { return (int)$arrayElement; },$elements);
    $array[$i] = $values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$runners = array(
    array('ENE' => "22", 'FEB' => "24"),
    array('MAR' => "16", 'ABR' => "33"),
    array('MAY' => "18", 'JUN' => "19")
);

$func = function($subarray){
    $tempArray = array();
    foreach($subarray as $key => $val)
    {
        $tempArray[$key] = (int)$val;
    }
    return $tempArray;
}

$new_array = array_map($func, $runners);
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Whats the difference between using a normal function and an Anonymous function? What is the equivalent of $func in a non-anonymous function?